# What should I use into rsa_pub_enc and rsa_pub_dec OpenSSL functions?

Tags: openssl, rsa

I code some OpenSSL ENGINE. 
It implements other RSA realisation with help hardware.

OpenSSL has function `ENGINE_set_RSA(ENGINE *e, const RSA_METHOD *rsa_meth);`. With help one I can set my new implementation.
Type `RSA_METHOD` contains pointers to realisation.

```
struct rsa_meth_st {
    const char *name;
    int (*rsa_pub_enc) (int flen, const unsigned char *from,
                        unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
    int (*rsa_pub_dec) (int flen, const unsigned char *from,
                        unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
    int (*rsa_priv_enc) (int flen, const unsigned char *from,
                         unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
    int (*rsa_priv_dec) (int flen, const unsigned char *from,
                         unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
    /* Can be null */
    int (*rsa_mod_exp) (BIGNUM *r0, const BIGNUM *I, RSA *rsa, BN_CTX *ctx);
    /* Can be null */
    int (*bn_mod_exp) (BIGNUM *r, const BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *p,
                       const BIGNUM *m, BN_CTX *ctx, BN_MONT_CTX *m_ctx);
    /* called at new */
    int (*init) (RSA *rsa);
    /* called at free */
    int (*finish) (RSA *rsa);
    /* RSA_METHOD_FLAG_* things */
    int flags;
    /* may be needed! */
    char *app_data;
    /*
     * New sign and verify functions: some libraries don't allow arbitrary
     * data to be signed/verified: this allows them to be used. Note: for
     * this to work the RSA_public_decrypt() and RSA_private_encrypt() should
     * *NOT* be used RSA_sign(), RSA_verify() should be used instead. Note:
     * for backwards compatibility this functionality is only enabled if the
     * RSA_FLAG_SIGN_VER option is set in 'flags'.
     */
    int (*rsa_sign) (int type,
                     const unsigned char *m, unsigned int m_length,
                     unsigned char *sigret, unsigned int *siglen,
                     const RSA *rsa);
    int (*rsa_verify) (int dtype, const unsigned char *m,
                       unsigned int m_length, const unsigned char *sigbuf,
                       unsigned int siglen, const RSA *rsa);
    /*
     * If this callback is NULL, the builtin software RSA key-gen will be
     * used. This is for behavioural compatibility whilst the code gets
     * rewired, but one day it would be nice to assume there are no such
     * things as "builtin software" implementations.
     */
    int (*rsa_keygen) (RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB *cb);
};
```

I don't understand what should do `rsa_pub_enc` and `rsa_pub_dec`.
Should it encrypt and decrypt with help only PUBlic key?

And I have the same question about `rsa_priv_enc/rsa_priv_dec`.
Should it encrypt and decrypt with help only PRIVate key?

I have already read https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RSA_public_encrypt.html and https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/RSA_public_decrypt.html, but I didn't understand.

Could anyone explain me it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encryption/decryption happens in this way:

1. **Encrypt using public key - Decrypt using private key** (Suggested and standard way)
   or
2. Encrypt using private key - Decrypt using public key

**Set 1**: Your `rsa_pub_enc` can point to implementation of `RSA_public_encrypt` and `rsa_priv_dec` can point to `RSA_private_decrypt`

**Set 2** : Your `rsa_priv_enc` can point to implementation of `RSA_private_encrypt` and `rsa_pub_dec` can point to `RSA_public_decrypt`

User **Set 1**  because it is always good to keep private key safe